# ¿Cómo guardar cambios de Documentos Arrays Embebidos con mongoose cuando se presenta el error "DivergentArrayError"?

Tags: mongoose

Tengo los siguientes esquemas:

```
let schZ = new Schema({
    z:{type: String} // más validaciones
});

let schY = new Schema({
    y:{type: String}, //más validaciones
    embZ:{type: schZ}
});

let schX = new Schema({
    x:{type: String}, //más validaciones
    embY:{type: schY}
});
```

Después de ejecutar una búsqueda con proyección, cuando intento salvar una modificación en el nivel más profundo, por ejemplo:

```
ModeloX.embY.embZ.z = "alguna modificacion";
ModeloX.save();
```

Obtengo:

> **error:"DivergentArrayError"**

Con el mensaje:

> For your own good, using `document.save()` to update an array which
>   was selected using an $elemMatch projection OR populated using skip,
>   limit, query conditions, or exclusion of the _id field when the
>   operation results in a $pop or $set of the entire array is not
>   supported. The following path(s) would have been modified unsafely:
>   embY Use Model.update() to update these arrays instead.

En la versión en inglés de stackoverflow está una [pregunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380919/divergentarrayerror-in-mongoose-while-updating-array-of-referenced-docs?rq=1).

Y dan como posible solución usar **findOneAndUpdate()**  o  **update()** y luego   **$set**  para cargar los cambios, sin embargo en la [documentación de mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html)    indica que al realizar esta actualización con métodos como **findOneAndUpdate()**  no se tendrá acceso a las validaciones y por lo tanto se recomienda usar **save()**

Nota: a nivel 1 de profundidad funciona sin problemas.

Comment: quita de tu pregunta, eso de `que otras opciones` por que eso es estar basada en opiniones y sería motivo o de cierre o de votos negativos

Comment: gracias ya lo modifiqué